# Get original touch location from UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

My view has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` added to it.
The problem is that by the time the touch is recognized as a pan gesture, it has to be moved a few points, and I can't extract the original touch location at the `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` state.
In this state the `translationInView:` is (0,0), and any subsequent moves are calculated from this point, and not from the original.

Is there a way to extract the original location from the gesture recognizer itself, or do I need to override the `touchesBegan:` method?

Comment: This link may help  - http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/

Comment: this is **very easy** these days,   it's just `sender.location(in: self)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to set the `delegate` for the gesture recogniser and implement

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

to get the initial touch.

Comment: This works, too. However, at the end I used `touchesBegan:`. It seems, the pan gesture recognizer really does not have a clue where the touch event originally started.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem by implementing a custom `PanGestureRecognizer` which saves the original touch point and makes it available to the caller.

I went this route as I also wanted to control the distance moved to trigger a *pan gesture*.

This might be overkill for your situation, but works perfectly and is less difficult than it sounds.

To get the touchpoint coordinates, you just call:

```
[sender touchPointInView:yourView]
```

instead of:

```
[sender locationInView:yourView]
```

Here's the code for `PanGestureRecognizer.m`:

```
#import "PanGestureRecognizer.h"
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@implementation PanGestureRecognizer

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    // touchPoint is defined as: @property (assign,nonatomic) CGPoint touchPoint;

    self.touchPoint = [touch locationInView:nil];   
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:nil];

    // customize the pan distance threshold

    CGFloat dx = fabs(p.x-self.touchPoint.x);
    CGFloat dy = fabs(p.y-self.touchPoint.y);

    if ( dx > 2 || dy > 2)  {
        if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {
            [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan];
        }
        else {
            [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged];
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded];
    }
    else {
        [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled];
    }
}

- (void) reset
{
}

// this returns the original touch point

- (CGPoint) touchPointInView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGPoint p = [view convertPoint:self.touchPoint fromView:nil];

    return p;
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't understand how one should use this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `locationInView:` rather than `translationInView:` you will get absolute coordinates instead of relative coordinates. However you do have to start the pan to get input... To work around this your view can be a UIButton and you can trigger a `- (IBAction)buttonWasTouched:(UIButton *)button forEvent:(UIEvent *)event` connected to `"touch down"` like so:

```
-(IBAction)shakeIntensityPanGesturebuttonWasTouched:(UIButton *)button forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view]; //touch location local cordinates
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `UIGestureRecognizerState`

```
- (void) onPanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        origin = [sender locationInView];
    } else {
        current = [sender locationInView];
        // Initial touch stored in origin
    }
}
```

Swift (ish):

```
var state = recognizer.state
if state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
    println(recognizer.locationInView(viewForGesture))
    //this will be the point of first touch
}
```

Comment: Gesture recognizers have different states (.Began, .Ended, .Cancelled, etc...). If you get the location of the (view or touch) when the recognizer state is .Began you will have its first location.

Comment: Place this code inside the function that gets called by the gesture. The println line above will only print one coordinate pair per touch/pan

Comment: Overriding `touchesBegan` and printing its value demonstrates it is not the same as the value returned by `locationInView` when the state is `.Began`.